# Is there a way to set a tag on an EC2 instance while creating it?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

Is that a way to create an EC2 instance with tags(I mean, adding tag as parameter when creating instance)

I can't find this function in boto APIs.  According to the document, we can only add tags after creating.

However, when creating on the browser, we can configure the tags when creating. So can we do the same thing in boto? (In our course we are required to tag our resource when creating, which is for bill monitor purpose, so adding tags after creating is not allowed.....)

Comment: Did you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575148/with-boto-how-can-i-name-a-newly-spawned-ec2-instance

Comment: What boto api are you using to create an instance?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, there is no way to do this in a single operation.